# Inserting a hero image into rmarkdown header

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to insert an banner image, with some text overlaid, across the header of an HTML document produced using rmarkdown. I am brand new to HTML but I have written a basic webpage that works (see below) and now I would like to insert it in the header of the HTML document.

Right now I'm just trying to make it work so I have been using this image called `melon.png`: [image: melon.png]

I have updated the boilerplate example in rmarkdown to use the `in_header` YAML field as follows:

````
---
title: "header_test"
author: "Dos"
date: "20 December 2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: C:/Users/Dos/Documents/html/CSS Backgrounds.html
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

The *CSS Backgrounds* HTML file referred to at *in_header* and the accompanying CSS files read as follows:

```css
div {
  height: 220px;
  width: 40cm;
  background-image: url('file:///C:/Users/Dos/Pictures/melon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40cm 12cm;
}
.center {
   margin: auto;
   padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Economic Note</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Dos/Documents/html/CSS Backgrounds css.CSS">
  </head>
<div class="center">
```

When I go to knit the file I get an error message:

> pandoc.exe: Could not fetch file:///C:/Users/Dos/Documents/html/CSS
>   Backgrounds css.CSS InvalidUrlException
>   "file:///C:/Users/Dos/Documents/html/CSS%20Backgrounds%20css.CSS"
>   "Invalid scheme" Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error
>   67 Execution halted

Any points on how I can go about this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to insert the HTML into the header. What you want to do is [modify the CSS of the RMarkdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html) itself.

Using your own example, I modified the YAML field to:

```
---
title: "header_test"
author: "Dos"
date: "20 December 2018"
output:
  html_document:
    css: "style.css"
---
```

And this is my `style.css` file:

```
body {
     color: white;
     background: url('/path/to/file') no-repeat top center;
}
```

I don't have enough reputation to add images, but the output has the image you posted as the background. I'm not too familiar with "hero" banner configurations, but I assume it is done through CSS, so you should be able to modify it however you like.